# Spring Cloud Zuul - which connection parameters work when?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

According to [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2069#issuecomment-319163725) comment, Zuul offers the following kinds of configuration parameters:

1. `zuul.host.*` : these include e.g. `max-per-route-connections` and `max-total-connections`. There are only relevant when routes are explicitly declared, as follows:

```yaml
---
zuul:
  host:
    max-per-route-connections: 500
    max-total-connections: 5000
  routes:
    my-service:
      path: /my-service/v1/**
      url: http://some-api/v1/
```

2. When using `Ribbon` together with `Eureka`, the `serviceId.ribbon.*` parameters should be used - or, more globally (AFAIK) `ribbon.*` e.g. `ribbon.MaxConnectionsPerHost`. These settings would apply for all Ribbon clients. So, if we have for example:

```yaml
---
ribbon:
  MaxConnectionsPerHost: 10
  MaxTotalConnections: 100
  ReadTimeout: 3000
```

and serviceA is registered via Eureka, then Zuul should create a `RibbonCommand` for the request with the above settings. This is seen in `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter#forward`:

```java
protected ClientHttpResponse forward(RibbonCommandContext context) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> info = this.helper.debug(context.getMethod(),
            context.getUri(), context.getHeaders(), context.getParams(),
            context.getRequestEntity());

        RibbonCommand command = this.ribbonCommandFactory.create(context);
    try {
        ClientHttpResponse response = command.execute();
        this.helper.appendDebug(info, response.getRawStatusCode(),
                response.getHeaders());
        return response;
    }
    catch (HystrixRuntimeException ex) {
        return handleException(info, ex);
    }

}
```

So far so good. Except, I can't validate this behaviour.

In my application, I've set the following parameters:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=test
-Dspring.cloud.config.label=local
-Deureka.client.defaultZone.serviceUrl=http://localhost:8761/eureka
-Deureka.instance.hostname=${spring.application.name}
-Dzuul.host.max-total-connections=2
-Dzuul.host.max-per-route-connections=2
-Dribbon.MaxTotalConnections=2
-Dribbon.MaxConnectionsPerHost=2
-Dribbon.MaxTotalHttpConnections=2
```

as well as the following config:

```yaml
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 150000
          strategy: SEMAPHORE
        timeout:
          enabled: false
```

Afterwards, when I make the first request against the given `service`, I see that `this.ribbonCommandFactory.create(context)` a new `HttpClientConnectionManager` is created (`org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.apache.HttpClientRibbonConfiguration.ApacheHttpClientConfiguration#httpClientConnectionManager`), which has `maxTotalConnections = 2` and `maxConnectionsPerHost = 2`.

Afterwards, I set a thread breakpoint just before `command.execute()`. I fire off >2 requests, expecting everything from the third onwards to complain about not being able to acquire a semaphore for execution.

What gives? Is this setting being checked *during* execute? Is my description above even correct? Which settings really apply when `ribbon` is being used with `serviceId`s?

I know that Spring Cloud Zuul is in maintenance mode, and I would like to switch to Spring Cloud Gateway ASAP, but I would still like to understand this behaviour.